# Countdown Timer sometime, counts 2 seconds before the actual time

Tags: android, listview, timer, countdown

I have tried to make an countdown timer in a list veiw implementation. Each list item has a separate countdown timer that can be started or stopped. However I have noticed that if I add the first timer in list and set its time. When I start the timer it starts two seconds less than the actual time. e.g If I added a count down of 12 seconds. Then it will start counting from 10. But when the countdown is taking place and I add another new timer and set its time, it starts on the exact given time. The new counter starts at the wrong time only when either there is no other counter in the list or when all counters are already stopped and not counting down. Similarly it will only start the right time only when other timers are counting down. Would really appreciate if someone can help me figure out where is the problem. I have been looking at the code for days.

Here's my Adapter class

```
public class CustomAdapterCounter extends ArrayAdapter<CounterData> {

private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
Context context;
Uri sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.tattooalarmclock.free/" + R.raw.counter);
String counterString = "";
private List<ViewHolder> lstHolders;
private List<CounterData> list = new ArrayList<CounterData>();
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable updateRemainingTimeRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (lstHolders) {
            long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (ViewHolder holder : lstHolders) {
              //  if(!holder.counterData.isStopped)
                    holder.updateTimeRemaining(System.currentTimeMillis());
            }
        }
    }
};

public CustomAdapterCounter(Context context, List<CounterData> l) {
    super(context, 0, l);
    this.context = context;
    lstHolders = new ArrayList<>();
    list = l;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
        CounterData[] array = list.toArray(new CounterData[list.size()]);
        if(!array[i].isStopped)
            startUpdateTimer();
    }
}

public double getScreenSize() {
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;
    int dens = dm.densityDpi;
    double wi = (double) width / (double) dens;
    double hi = (double) height / (double) dens;
    double x = Math.pow(wi, 2);
    double y = Math.pow(hi, 2);
    double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x + y);

    return screenInches;
}


private void startUpdateTimer() {
    Timer tmr = new Timer();
    tmr.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mHandler.post(updateRemainingTimeRunnable);
        }
    }, 1000, 1000);
}

public static <T> List<T> stringToArray(String s, Class<T[]> clazz) {
    T[] arr = new Gson().fromJson(s, clazz);
    return Arrays.asList(arr); //or return Arrays.asList(new Gson().fromJson(s, clazz)); for a one-liner
}


public boolean getListSharedPreferences() {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (sharedPreferences.getString("CL", null) != null) {
            counterString = sharedPreferences.getString("CL", null);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            TypeToken<List<CounterData>> token = new TypeToken<List<CounterData>>() {};
            list = gson.fromJson(counterString, token.getType());
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}

public void saveListSharedPreferences(List counterList) {

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    counterString = gson.toJson(counterList);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    sharedPreferences.edit().putString("CL", counterString).commit();

}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        if(getScreenSize() <= 4 )
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_counter_small, parent, false);
        else
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_item_counter, parent, false);
        holder.counterTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.counterTextView);
        holder.stopCounter = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.counterStopInList);
        holder.startCounter = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.counterStartInList);
        holder.deleteCounter = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deleteCounter);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        synchronized (lstHolders) {
            lstHolders.add(holder);
        }

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.setData2(getItem(position));

    final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;
    holder.stopCounter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            long store = finalHolder.counterData.expirationTime - System.currentTimeMillis();
            finalHolder.counterData.isStopped = true;
            finalHolder.counterData.expirationTime = store;
            finalHolder.stopCounter.setEnabled(false);
            finalHolder.stopCounter.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
            finalHolder.startCounter.setEnabled(true);
            finalHolder.startCounter.getBackground().setColorFilter(null);
            list.set(position, finalHolder.counterData);
            saveListSharedPreferences(list);

       /*     if(getListSharedPreferences()) {
                System.out.println("List before change in stop button " + list.toString());
                list = stringToArray(counterString, CounterData[].class);
                list.set(position, finalHolder.counterData);
                System.out.println("List before change in stop button " + list.toString());
                saveListSharedPreferences(list);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(list.toString());
                list.set(position, finalHolder.counterData);
                System.out.println(list.toString());
                saveListSharedPreferences(list);
            }
        */
        }
    });

    holder.startCounter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finalHolder.counterData.expirationTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + finalHolder.counterData.expirationTime;
            finalHolder.counterData.isStopped = false;
            //finalHolder.counterData.expirationTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + finalHolder.counterData.expirationTime;
            //finalHolder.setData(finalHolder.counterData);
            finalHolder.startCounter.setEnabled(true);
            finalHolder.startCounter.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
            finalHolder.stopCounter.setEnabled(true);
            finalHolder.stopCounter.getBackground().setColorFilter(null);
            list.set(position, finalHolder.counterData);
            saveListSharedPreferences(list);
            startUpdateTimer();
       /*     if(getListSharedPreferences()) {
                list = stringToArray(counterString, CounterData[].class);
                System.out.println("List before change in start button " + list.toString());
                list.set(position, finalHolder.counterData);
                System.out.println("List after change in start button " + list.toString());
                saveListSharedPreferences(list);
            }
            else {
                list.set(position, finalHolder.counterData);
                saveListSharedPreferences(list);
            } */
        }
    });

    final ViewHolder finalHolder1 = holder;
    holder.deleteCounter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
 /*           if(finalHolder1.mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                finalHolder.mediaPlayer.stop();
          //      finalHolder.counterData.isSoundPlayedBefore = true;
            } */
            list.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            saveListSharedPreferences(list);
        }
    });


    return convertView;
}
}

 class ViewHolder {
 public TextView counterTextView;
 //public List<Long> l;
 CounterData counterData;
 Button startCounter;
 Button stopCounter;
 Button deleteCounter;
 boolean stop = false;
 long timeDiff;
// Context context;
// MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
// List<CounterData> counterDataList;

 public void setData(CounterData item) {
     counterData = item;
     updateTimeRemaining(System.currentTimeMillis());
 }

 public void setData2(CounterData item) {
     counterData = item;
     updateTimeRemaining(System.currentTimeMillis());
 }

 public void updateTimeRemaining(long currentTime) {

     if (!counterData.isStopped) {
         timeDiff = counterData.expirationTime - currentTime;
         //System.out.println("Time Diff Inside Method " + timeDiff);
         if (timeDiff > 0) {
             int seconds = (int) (timeDiff / 1000) % 60;
             int minutes = (int) ((timeDiff / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
             int hours = (int) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(timeDiff);
             counterTextView.setText(hours + "H " + minutes + "M " + seconds + "S");
             stopCounter.setEnabled(true);
             stopCounter.getBackground().setColorFilter(null);
             startCounter.setEnabled(false);
             startCounter.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
         } else {
             counterTextView.setText("Times Up");
             startCounter.setEnabled(false);
             startCounter.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
             stopCounter.setEnabled(false);
             stopCounter.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
         //    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) this.context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
             // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
         //    v.vibrate(5000);
     /*        if(!counterData.isSoundPlayedBefore) {
                 mediaPlayer.start();
                 mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                         mediaPlayer.stop();
                     }
                 });
                 counterData.isSoundPlayedBefore = true;
                 if(findIndex(counterData) != -1) {
                     int index = findIndex(counterData);
                     counterDataList.set(index,counterData);
                     saveListSharedPreferences(counterDataList);
                 }
             } */
         }
     }
     else {
         long store = counterData.expirationTime + System.currentTimeMillis() - currentTime;
         int seconds = (int) (store / 1000) % 60;
         int minutes = (int) ((store / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
         int hours = (int) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(store);
         counterTextView.setText(hours + "H " + minutes + "M " + seconds + "S");
         startCounter.setEnabled(true);
         startCounter.getBackground().setColorFilter(null);
         stopCounter.setEnabled(false);
         stopCounter.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
     }
 }
 }
```

And here's my CounterData class

```
class CounterData {
long expirationTime;
boolean isStopped;
boolean isSoundPlayedBefore;
int id;

public CounterData(long expirationTime, int id) {
    this.expirationTime = expirationTime;
    isStopped = true;
    isSoundPlayedBefore = false;
    this.id = id;
}

public String toString() {

    return String.valueOf("Remaining Time: " + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(this.expirationTime) + ":" + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(this.expirationTime));
}

public void setCounterID(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getCounterID() {
    return this.id;
}

 }
```

And I add the time from number pickers of Hour, Minute and Second.

```
 case R.id.counterStartStopButton:
            long hour = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(numberPickerHour.getValue());
            long minute = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(numberPickerMinute.getValue());
            long second = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(numberPickerSecond.getValue());
      //      if(getListSharedPreferences()) {
                if(getCounterIDSharedPreferences()) {
                    counterID = counterID + 1;
                    list.add(new CounterData(hour + minute + second, counterID));
                    saveCounterIDSharedPreferences(counterID);
                }
                else {
                    counterID = 1;
                    list.add(new CounterData(hour + minute + second, counterID));
                    saveCounterIDSharedPreferences(counterID);
                }
```

UPDATE
Here's the shared preferences code

```
public void saveCounterIDSharedPreferences(int id) {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("Counter ID123", id).commit();
}


public boolean getCounterIDSharedPreferences() {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (sharedPreferences.getInt("Counter ID123", -1) != -1) {
        counterID = sharedPreferences.getInt("Counter ID123", -1);
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: So your first timer is starting at 10 (2s delay) but after that everything is ok?

Comment: If there is no other timer or if all other timers in the list are paused, if I add a new timer it will start start counting from (actual time -2 seconds). If the other counter(s) in the list are counting down and are not stopped, and if I add a new counter in this case, it starts fine.

Comment: Can you post the CounterIdSharedPref code?

Comment: please see the update in the original post. I have pasted the code there.

Comment: I think the problem comes from: tmr.schedule(new TimerTask()..., 1000, 1000); You have given 1s delay. If you set 12s, then it starts at 11s but there are also some code execution time before you display the timer, so it becomes 10.XXXs. As you only displayed the integer part, therefore it becomes 10s.

Comment: I tried changing it to  tmr.schedule(new TimerTask()..., 1000, 100); but it doesn't change anything. How do you think I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

What turned out to work for me was changing the timer task as following:

```
 private void startUpdateTimer() {
    Timer tmr = new Timer();
    tmr.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mHandler.post(updateRemainingTimeRunnable);
        }
    }, 500, 500);
}
```